# Django QuerySet ordering by number of reverse ForeignKey matches

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'Title'), max_length=600)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    eg_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Example ID'), default=0)
```

I wish to return a list of `Foo` objects which have a reverse relationship with `Bar` objects that have a `eg_id` value contained in a list of values. So I have:

```
id_list = [7, 8, 9, 10]
qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar__eg_id__in=id_list)
```

How do I order the matching `Foo` objects according to the number of related `Bar` objects which have an `eg_id` value in the `id_list`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Django's lovely [aggregation features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
from django.db.models import Count
qs = Foo.objects.filter(
           bar__eg_id__in=id_list
      ).annotate(
           bar_count=Count('bar')
      ).order_by('bar_count')
```

Comment: Thanks. Only recently upgraded from Django 1.0 so the aggregation feature is still rather new to me.

Comment: As a follow up.  I tried to add the filter as a property into my my "Foo" model object.  even though i import the 'Bar' model, django shell says 'bar' in Count('bar') is not identified.  Why does it work in my view.py but not in my model.py?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), and more especifically [annotation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and [order_by](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by).

In your example, it would be:

```
from django.db.models import Count

id_list = [7, 8, 9, 10]
qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar__eg_id__in=id_list)
qs = qs.annotate(count=Count("bar"))
qs = qs.order_by('-count')
```