# Django filter sort by number of ForeignKey related objects

Tags: python, django

I have a website which catalogs hikes, and users can log that they have gone on these hikes. I have a search function, and I want to be able to sort my list of hikes by the amount of times they have been completed by my users. I found this post which seems relevant, but is referring to a specific field in the foreignkey model, whereas I'd like to just count the total number of instances: 
[Django QuerySet ordering by number of reverse ForeignKey matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453821/django-queryset-ordering-by-number-of-reverse-foreignkey-matches)

Here is some sample code:

models.py:

```
class Hikes(models.Model)
...    

class UserLog(models.Model)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
     hike = models.ForeignKey(Hikes, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

I need to generate a queryset from my Hikes model that counts the number of times UserLog has referenced each hike, and then orders the hikes from most referenced to least. Something like this:

Hikes.objects.order_by(for each hike, count # of references in UserLog, then place in order by # of references)

So if Hike #1 has 10 UserLog instances, Hike #2 has 20, and Hike #3 has 5, the QuerySet would return:
Hike #2, Hike #1, Hike #3

Any tips?

Edit: thanks to viviwill, here is the working code in a search field:

```
def hike_list(request):
    qs = Hikes.objects.all()
    ...
    if request.GET:
        ...
        searchsort = request.GET.get('sortby', '')
        if searchsort == 'sortlocalrepeats':
            qs = qs.annotate(count=Count('userlog')).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In views:

```
context['rank_hike'] = Hikes.objects.annotate(number_of_hikes=Count('UserLog')).order_by('-number_of_hikes')
```

In the template:

```
{% for hike in rank_hike %}
<p>{{ hike }} {{ hike.number_of_entries }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I am actually using it as a sort option in a search field, but was able to modify it to work. Thank you! I've edited my original post to include my final code.

Comment: It will give you duplicate values.