# Ranking Model A by Model B

Tags: django

I have a Game Model and a Subscription Model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to sort Games by the number of subscribers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter sort by number of ForeignKey related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449511/django-filter-sort-by-number-of-foreignkey-related-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Django >= 2.0:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    # Previous code

    class Meta:
        ordering = [Count('subscription').desc(nulls_last=True)]
```

In older versions you can do this:

```
Game.objects.all().annotate(num_subscribers=Count('subscription')
                  .order_by('-num_subscribers')
```