# Django how to find sum of reverse FK and reverse FK of the reverse FK

Tags: python, django, django-models

Due to an *absolutely fantastic* DB design, I've stumbled across an issue. I'm counting the number of reverse FK matches and ITS reverse FK matches (following the method in this SO question: [Django QuerySet ordering by number of reverse ForeignKey matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2453821)). I tried doing:

```
assert 6 == Model.objects.annotate(counting=Count(f"blah1") + Count(f"blah1__blah2")).get(id=1).counting
```

But I'm getting `6 == 7` as in my query is always giving me an extra 1. Why is that?

Edit: the models:

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    ...

class Blah1(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Blah2(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Blah1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: `Count('blah1')` will count the same number of items as `Count('blah1__blah2')`, because you made a JOIN.

Comment: Ah so the JOIN is giving the extra 1? I should just get rid of the `Count("blah1")`?

Comment: no normally it will simply count all non-`NULL`s extra. But I would advise to share (relevant parts) of your model (you can obfuscate the names), and sample data.

Comment: Updated with models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count('blah1')` will count the same number of items as `Count('blah1__blah2')`, because you made a JOIN. Indeed the query looks like:

```
SELECT model.*, COUNT(blah1.id) + COUNT(blah2.id) AS counting
FROM model
LEFT OUTER JOIN blah1.parent = model.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN blah2.parent = blah1.id
```

`COUNT` does *not* care about the values, or the values being duplicates, it only will not count `NULL`s, but for the rest, `COUNT(blah1.id)` and `COUNT(blah2.id)` will probably be nearly identical.

You thus should count *unique* values for `blah1`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Model.objects.annotate(
    counting=Count('blah1', distinct=True) +
             Count('blah1__blah2')
).get(id=1).counting
```

Here we will thus only count the distinct `blah1` objects.